# How Do I loop through this class once I have added items

Tags: vb.net, winforms

How do i loop through this class once I add items via this method. Just I am quite new to generic lists so was wonding if someone could point me in right direction in datatables im used to doing the following:

```
For Each thisentry In dt.rows

Next
```

What do I use in collections

Calling Code 
Calling this in my delciarations of main class

```
Dim infoNoProductAvail As List(Of infoProductsNotFound) = New List(Of infoProductsNotFound)()
```

this is how i am adding the files but I have checked in the routine and the count for the list is at 2 products

```
     If medProductInfo.SKU.SKUID = 0 Then
            infoNoProductAvail.Add(New infoProductsNotFound(thisenty2.Item("EAN13").ToString(), True))
        End If
```

this is the class itselfs

```
    Public Class infoProductsNotFound
        Public Sub New(tbcode As String, notfound As Boolean)
            Me.tagbarcode = tbcode
            Me.notfound = notfound

        End Sub
        Private tagbarcode As String = String.Empty
        Private notfound As Boolean

        Public Property tbcode() As String
            Get
                Return tagbarcode
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                tagbarcode = value
            End Set

        End Property

        Public Property isNotFound() As Boolean
            Get
                Return notfound
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
                notfound = value
            End Set

        End Property
    End Class
```

Tried

I tried using the following

```
         Function BuildExceptionsForEmail()
            Dim retval As String = ""
            Dim cnt As Int32 = 0
            retval = "The following products are not avialable" & vbCrLf
            For Each info As infoProductsNotFound In infoNoProductAvail


                     retval &= info.tbcode

                    cnt &= 1
            Next
            Return retval
```

but for some reason at this point my info noproductAvail is blank even though in the routine above its sitting at count of 2 what gives?

Comment: foreach thisentry in infoNoProductAvail ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I'd shrink that declaration a bit:

```
Dim infoNoProductAvail As New List(Of infoProductsNotFound)
```

Next, to iterate there are several options. First (and what you're likely most used to):

```
For Each info as infoProductsNotFound in infoNoProductAvail 

    If info.tbCode = "xyz" Then
        DoSomething(info)
    End If

Next
```

Or you might want to use lambda expressions (if you're using .Net 3.5 and above I think - might be .Net 4):

```
infoNoProductAvail.ForEach (Function(item) DoSomething(item))
```

Remember that generics are strongly typed (unlike the old VB collections) so no need to cast whatever comes out: you can access properties and methods directly.

```
If infoNoProductAvail(3).isNotFound Then
    'Do something 
End If
```

(Not that that is a great example, but you get the idea).

Comment: LINQ and Lambda expressions were added in 3.5.  However, the `List(Of T).ForEach` method predates LINQ.  It goes back to 2.0.  Also, since Lambda expressions are a function of the compiler, you can use them when targeting older framework versions, as long as you are using a newer version of Visual Studio to compile it.  Therefore, as long as you are using a newish version of Visual Studio, you can use this example code even when targeting the 2.0 framework.

Comment: Nice! You learn something new every day. I hadn't realised `List(Of T).ForEach` existed before 3.5, I suppose because I hadn't really had any exposure to LINQ or lambda expressions before then.

Comment: @StevePettifer thanks for the answer im part of the way their but in my build for email i am not getting any info through even though on above in my routine where I add items to class its sitting at a count of 2 any suggesions?

Comment: Hard to say - Can you edit your question to include a condensed version of your class (i.e. the Class...End Class with the bit where the list is declared, the bit where it's populated and the BuildExceptions function - leave out any database code and the like, just the stuff directly related to the problem). Should really be another question but that might be overkill.

Comment: That hasn't helped because you've just made the code block larger. It doesn't explain where your call to BuildExceptionsForEmail is in relation to anything else. Go to [DotNet Fiddle](http://dotnetfiddle.net/) and put a skeleton version of your class in there (excluding the infoProductsNotFound sub-class). Once you've entered it and selected VB in the language dropdown, click Run and then click Share and get the link from there and post back here. That way I can look at it without you editing your question.

Answer (score 1):

The `For Each` syntax is the same.  It works the same way for all `IEnumerable` objects.  The only "trick" to it is to make sure that your iterator variable is of the correct type, and also to make sure that you are iterating through the correct object.

In the case of the `DataTable`, you are iterating over it's `Rows` property.  That property is an `IEnumerable` object containing a list of `DataRow` objects.  Therefore, to iterate through it with `For Each`, you must use an iterator variable of type `DataRow` (or one of its base classes, such as `Object`).

To iterate through a generic `List(Of T)`, the `IEnumerable` object is the `List` object itself.  You don't need to go to one of it's properties.  The type of the iterator needs to match the type of the items in the list:

```
For Each i As infoProductsNotFound In infoNoProductAvail
    ' ...
Next
```

Or:

```
Dim i As infoProductsNotFound
For Each i In infoNoProductAvail
    ' ...
Next
```

Or:

```
For Each i As Object In infoNoProductAvail
    ' ...
Next
```

Etc.

Comment: this is also the correct answer why marking both up